# Eclipse import a plugin as source project but it's not include src folder

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to modify the plugin org.eclipse.jface.text's source code and build my own plugin.I opened the Plug-ins window(`Window > Show View > Plug-ins`),found org.eclipse.jface.text,`right click > Import as > Source Project`. Serveal seconds later, I can find the project org.eclipse.jface.text on Package Explorer. However,this project does not include src folder and I can't find any `.java` files, it's a Binary Project.

My Eclipse Info:
Type: Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Indigo Service Release 2
Build id: 20120216-1857

Can someone give me a solusion to solve this problem?

Comment: I would think twice before modifying Eclipse plugins. You are going to make it much more difficult to give code to other people.

Comment: @greg-449 I just modify this plugin in my own PC, to make it more convenient to use for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you should try importing the plugin with the source using the dedicated wizard(`File > Import... > Plug-in Development > Plug-ins`) as shown in [this page](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.pde.doc.user%2Fguide%2Ftools%2Fimport_wizards%2Fimport_plugins.htm) of the official Eclipse documentation.

Comment: So does the result as the former. I think I should download this project by browser, though it's not as convinent as above way.Thank you anyway.

Comment: @robothy This does work if you use 'Project with source folders' in the import **and** you have the Eclipse source code plugins installed (install the 'Eclipse SDK' if you don't have these).